# How can I check how many bytes a reference requires?

Tags: c#, .net, reference

From [C# 5.0 in a Nutshell: The Definitive Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449320104) in page 22;

> *Reference types require separate allocations of memory for the
>   reference and object. The object consumes as many bytes as its fields,
>   plus additional administrative overhead. The precise overhead is
>   intrinsically private to the implementation of the .NET runtime, but
>   at minimum the overhead is eight bytes, used to store a key to the
>   object’s type, as well as temporary information such as its lock state
>   for multithreading and a flag to indicate whether it has been fixed
>   from movement by the garbage collector. **Each reference to an object
>   requires an extra four or eight bytes, depending on whether the .NET
>   runtime is running on a 32- or 64-bit platform.***

I'm not quite sure I understand this bold part completely. It says on 32-bit platforms a reference requires four bytes, on 64-bit platforms it requires eight bytes.

So, let's say we have

```
string s = "Soner";
```

How can I check how many bytes this `s` reference requires?

Comment: Can you tell us, why you would ever want to check that programmatically? Those are **implementation details** for a reason. If you need that information, you are very likely doing something bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Environment.Is64BitProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitprocess.aspx). If it is, every reference will be 8 bytes. If it's not, every reference will be 4 bytes. The type of the reference, and the contents of the object it refers to, are irrelevant.

EDIT: As noted in a now-deleted answer, [`IntPtr.Size`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.size.aspx) is even simpler.

EDIT: As noted in comments, although *currently* all references in a CLR are the same size, it's just possible that at some point it will go down a similar path to Hotspot, which uses "compressed oops" in many cases to store references as 32-bit values even in a 64-bit process (without limiting the memory available).

Comment: Thanks Jon, but is there any other way to find this just using `s` reference instead of checking the platform is 64-bit or not?

Comment: @SonerGönül: Not easily, no. Why would you want to? It's not like it depends on the reference - it depends on whether you're using a 64-bit CLR.

Comment: @SonerGönül: If that's what you really want, my answer tells you how.

Comment: Simon Belanger's (deleted) answer is perhaps better, use IntPtr.Size.  Which will still work on those future 128-bit platforms (though 640K ought to be enough for anyone)

Comment: @Joe: It's worth noting, I don't know if .NET has reserved the right to do this in the future, but trying something like `IntPtr.Size` wouldn't work if .NET decides to use [compressed references like Java sometimes does](https://blogs.oracle.com/jrockit/entry/understanding_compressed_refer). `sizeof(GCHandle)` *could* be closer to the truth, but not necessarily.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I considered that - but I think it unlikely at this point.

Comment: @Joe: As that's been deleted, I'll add it into my answer. If Simon wants to undelete his answer, I can remove it then.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yeah it's unlikely all right, just worth mentioning I think.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Simon should undelete, he needs the rep points more than you :)

Answer (score 2):

If you **really** want to *calculate* the size of a reference, using this `Reference.Size` should work:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

public static class Reference
{
    public static readonly int Size = new Func<int>(delegate()
    {
        var method = new DynamicMethod(string.Empty, typeof(int), null);
        var gen = method.GetILGenerator();
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Sizeof, typeof(object));
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_I4);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        return ((Func<int>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int>)))();
    })();
}
```

But going with the other answers is probably a better idea.

Comment: @SonerGönül: Huh? The size of `s` doesn't depend on `s` itself (Jon mentioned that above), it only depends on the **type** of `s`, which is some subclass of `object`. So `Reference.Size` gives you the value you need.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Jon Skeet's answer, to get the number of possible bytes you should do this:

```
int bytesInRef = Environment.Is64BitProcess ? 8 : 4;
```

However, this is an **implementation detail.** Not only should you not worry about this, you should ignore this. Here's a good blog post on (another) implementation detail, but it's still applicable as it talks about implementation details and how you shouldn't trust them or depend on them. Here: [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx)